# How to Get the Control Type in a Gridview Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How would you get the control type of an EditTemplate control in a gridview in ASP.NET?

To get a bound control's type I simply do this

```
foreach (TableCell cell in grdViewDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
{               
    //set the employeeid so you can update the dataset
    if (cell.Controls[0] is CheckBox)
    {
       CheckBox check = (CheckBox)cell.Controls[0];
       //Do stuff with the control and the text inside the control etc;
    }
}
```

but I cant seem to find the controls in the templates. They just skip this if.

What I've tried to no avail.

```
foreach (TableCell cell in grdViewDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
{  
    var test1 = cell.Controls[0];
    columnName = dsOriginal.Tables[0].Columns[startOfColumns].ColumnName; //[System.Web.UI.LiteralControl] I can find the Column Name but it't not a normal control... It's a LiteralControl?
    var test2 = cell.FindControl("CheckWeek2");  //[System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar] = {SelectedDate = The name 'SelectedData' does not exist in the current context}
}
```

My Gridview control Template

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="week2" SortExpression="week2">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckWeek2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("week2") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="Label2" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%# Bind("week2") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Which event you try to find edit template controls?

Comment: I want to get the Text/ischecked of the control that is being edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below,

```
if (this.grdViewDetails.EditIndex != -1)
{
 CheckBox b = grdViewDetails.Rows[grdViewDetails.EditIndex].FindControl("CheckWeek2") as CheckBox;
 if (b != null)
  {
  //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did actually work.
this didn't "CheckBox c = grdViewDetails.Rows[grdViewDetails.EditIndex].Controls[8] as CheckBox;" (gives null)
but your way did, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox CheckWeek2 = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("CheckWeek2");

        }
```